# Setting JavaFx's ScrollPane's Vvalue does not reflect change in very certain scenario

Tags: java, javafx

Setting Vvalue of ScrollPane does not show change if:

- we change Vvalue of scrollpane inside action invoked by clicking a Button
- we disable that button inside that action
- scrollpane's content is complex enough

*I am not sure if it is directly (or only) caused by these three conditions, but this example shows what I mean.*

Minimal reproducible example:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("javafx.runtime.version"));
        var showButton = new Button("CLICK ME");

        var sp = new ScrollPane();

        var vbox = new VBox();
        var vbox2 = new VBox();

        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            vbox2.getChildren().addAll(
                    new Label("dummy"),
                    new HBox(new HBox()),
                    new GridPane(),
                    new Button("dummy"));
        }

        showButton.setOnAction(event -> {
            sp.setVvalue(0.5);
            // sp's Vvalue is not rendered if we disable button here while also having a complex content
            // complex content created above should be enough, if not try to increase 'i < 200' to 'i < 1000' or more
            showButton.setDisable(true);
        });

        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(50,50,50,50));
        vbox.setSpacing(50);

        vbox.getChildren().addAll(showButton, vbox2);

        sp.setContent(vbox);

        var scene = new Scene(sp);
        primaryStage.setWidth(150);
        primaryStage.setHeight(150);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Start the Application, click on the CLICK ME button and see that the scrollpane is not scrolled.

If we do not disable the button (remove line with `showButton.setDisable(true);`) inside that action or content is not complex enough (try reducing the `i` to 5) the scrollpane is scrolled normally. **EDIT:** reducing complexity by having less items in vbox2 did not play a role.

How I found this (possible) bug:

In my application I have a scenario that when user clicks a button, content is shown and scrollpane inside which the button is should be scrolled up while also disabling the button to prevent user clicking it another time. However, the scrollpane is not scrolled due to these reasons described above.

Wrapping setting Vvalue in another Thread with `sleep()` like so works:, **but it is not right**:

```
    ...
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        sp.setVvalue(0.5);
    }).start();
    showButton.setDisable(true);
    ...
```

I am on Kubuntu 23.04 (Linux) using JavaFX 17.0.8+1+b01

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the button losing focus because it was disabled. This causes the focus to go to the next focusable node in the scene graph, and this functionality goes through the "traversal engine". And the default skin of `ScrollPane` adds [the following listener](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/be2c7aea20c7752f069e526d2c3f9bea11bc1634/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/skin/ScrollPaneSkin.java#L635) to the engine:

> ```java
> traversalEngine.addTraverseListener((node, bounds) -> {
>    // auto-scroll so node is within (0,0),(contentWidth,contentHeight)
>    scrollBoundsIntoView(bounds);
> });
> ```

This listener serves an important purpose. It allows the user to e.g., <kbd>Tab</kbd> through controls in the scroll pane and have the scroll pane automatically scroll to make sure the newly focused control is visible. So, I would not call this behavior a bug<sup>1</sup>. But it is also unfortunately causing your issue, because the next focused node is the first button in `vbox2`, which causes the scroll pane to scroll back up to the top after you call `sp.setVvalue(0.5)`.

A workaround, at least for this example code, is to simply request a different node take focus before disabling the button. For instance, you could focus the `ScrollPane`:

```java
showButton.setOnAction(e -> {
    sp.requestFocus();
    showButton.setDisable(true);
    sp.setVvalue(0.5);
}
```

---

<sup>1. Unless you believe `ScrollPaneSkin` could implement this behavior via a different mechanism than the traversal engine.</sup>

Comment: Another possible workaround:  `vbox2.getChildren().forEach(c -> c.setFocusTraversable(false));`

Comment: Thanks. Setting focus to something else before disabling the button works!